# Using HTTPS on WildFly throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed

Tags: ssl, wildfly, illegalargumentexception

I have a JSF application. App is running on wildfly app server. If I'm using HTTP everything works great, but when I'm using https, I'm getting this exception:

```
UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET localhost:8433/index.xhtml request {accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.9,lv-LV;q=0.8,lv;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5], cache-control=[max-age=0], sec-fetch-mode=[navigate], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36], sec-fetch-user=[?1], sec-fetch-dest=[document], sec-fetch-site=[none], cookie=[cl_language_code=LV, JSESSIONID=PNg2m-pZqBHlDJmxpP-VG9Go_TGbQdv2pN_8yTKN.desktop-dcuvc4o, cl_language_code=LV, _ga=GA1.1.1203884466.1567082977, JSESSIONID.bfdfec56=node04glctasu5mkh1hwkt9b7o89rk2.node0, screenResolution=1920x1080, JSESSIONID.44483941=node0l4m14av490poi6267xkjyz581.node0, JSESSIONID.94e8f158=node01uoen3g7huxr88i2nl97xiako1.node0, jenkins-timestamper-offset=-10800000, JSESSIONID.a5642775=node01pumga5xohfyrt6lq2box369c1.node0, _gid=GA1.1.1938803944.1588231358, JSESSIONID=oOyaWkIMTnwto_zofOqGCBP3cSOIaorH5ohUuvNH.desktop-dcuvc4o], upgrade-insecure-requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8443]} response {}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:88)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:151)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:386)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetAttributeHandler.handleRequest(SetAttributeHandler.java:110)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$AcmeResourceHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:405)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$HostRootHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:414)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.NameVirtualHostHandler.handleRequest(NameVirtualHostHandler.java:54)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.error.SimpleErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SimpleErrorPageHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Server$DefaultHostHandler.handleRequest(Server.java:189)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.ChannelUpgradeHandler.handleRequest(ChannelUpgradeHandler.java:211)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.handleRequest(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:102)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisallowedMethodsHandler.handleRequest(DisallowedMethodsHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2ReceiveListener.handleRequests(Http2ReceiveListener.java:230)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2ReceiveListener.handleEvent(Http2ReceiveListener.java:120)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2ReceiveListener.handleEvent(Http2ReceiveListener.java:63)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:948)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:929)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1175)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

I cannot understand where is a problem.

Comment: Did you somewhere typo a port 8433 instead of 8443? `GET localhost:8433/index.xhtml` clearly doesn't match `Host=[localhost:8443]`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. I had filter in standalone.xml, which redirected from 8443 to 8433

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I had filter in standalone.xml, which redirected from 8443 to 8433